# Which is better SICP or HTDP

Tags: computer-science, sicp

I have read that SICP ([Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/))  is hard and HTDP ([How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/)) is better as an introductory course.
I would say I am fairly good in maths but not a genius.So how hard is SICP, is it harder than knuth or cormen.

Comment: Hi Sumit Jain, unfortunately, [broad comparisons are not a fit for the Stack Exchange format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), and questions asking what you should learn are off-topic: if, after doing your own research and homework, you have specific questions, feel free to ask those instead.

Comment: The question is closed, but one part is definitely answerable: the SICP is less difficult than Knuth and Cormen's books. The SCIP is typically for a first-year course, while Cormen's is typically for second-year courses.

Answer (score 3):

Difficulty varies from person to person. I've read SICP, Art of Computer Programming, and Intro to Algorithms and I found them easy - however, I had a great teacher in all my classes, a lot of support from other students and teaching fellows as well as help online. Furthermore, I've always loved both math and computer programming, and I excel in those subjects.

As far as compartively, I'd say SICP, Art of Computer Programming, and Intro to Algorithms are all around the same level of difficulty, perhaps SICP being slightly easier in some ways.

HTDP is probably easier. As far as which is better, is really anyone's guess. I'd bet that a lot of people on here prefer SICP simply because it's what they learned with.

Comment: You found [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) easy?  Are you sure you're not thinking of some other book?

Comment: Yes, I picked up Knuth once and never had the courage to read it again.

Comment: I picked up Knuth once and shouted "Put me down!"

Comment: @Keith Did the book say that or did you?

Comment: @user16764: Sorry, I accidentally a word there.  What I meant to write was: I picked up Knuth once and he shouted "Put me down!"